# Is it possible to sync Sharepoint Contact List with Iphone contacts (or Outlook App on iphone)

Tags: contacts

Is it possible to sync Sharepoint Contact List with Iphone contacts (or Outlook App on iphone)?

We have the company contacts stored as a List on our Sharepoint Site, we have added the folder to Outlook on our office pcs - all fine, but would like to give the team access on their mobile phones (iphone and android) - and ideally (although not essential as straight access would be better than nothing).

I have seen that we can use some third party software to do this, it just seems that this seems to have been a problem for a number of businesses in the past, was a solution found?

If we still need to use a  third party software, are there any recommendations?

Any help/advice very much appreciated. Thanks
J

Comment: I know your post is a year old now but curious, did you ever find an answer for this? I currently have this issue now. Client has a sharepoint contact list they want synced to iphones without using a 3rd party software. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately not and the third party software I found wasnt a viable option for a small business with few users but a lot of contacts.  Thinking outside the box one option that was suggested to me was to use Google Contacts to manage contacts - which apparently syncs with phones and pc's (or macs) and although the Directors didnt go for it, I personally thought that was a very good work around. Good luck with your search and please let me know if you find a solution - Im sure one day there will be one!

Comment: Have you considered using a powerapp? This gives you control of what contact info is shown.